# XSLT for each list value for specified id

Tags: for-loop, xslt, each

I try list value in deep level parameter, but only specified parameter.
I do for each test id for 706 number, when true I do for each and list value name. I need too semicolon between values but not at the beginning and at the end.

XML:

```
 <parameters>
<section id="27" name="Parametry produktu"/>
<parameter id="23" name="kolor">
  <value id="42" name="jasny róż"/>
</parameter>
<parameter id="25" name="skład">
  <value id="43" name="97% bawełna, 3% poliamid"/>
</parameter>
<parameter id="706" name="rozmiar (ukryć)"">
  <value id="717" name="46"/>
  <value id="718" name="47"/>
  <value id="719" name="48"/>
</parameter>
<parameter id="142" name="płeć (ukryć)">
  <value id="746" name="ona"/>
</parameter>
</parameters>
```

XSLT:

```
             <sizes3>
          <xsl:for-each select="parameters">
           <xsl:if test="parameter/@id = 706">
            <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
              <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="position() = 1"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="value/@name" />
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('; ', value/@name)" />                 
               </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>                                     
           </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>             
         </sizes3>
```

Result is:

```
<sizes3>jasny róż; 97% bawełna, 3% poliamid;46; ona;</sizes3>
```

But i need:

```
<sizes3>46;47;48</sizes3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/parameters">
    <!-- other stuff ? -->
    <sizes3>
        <xsl:for-each select="parameter[@id=706]/value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> 
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </sizes3>
    <!-- more stuff ? -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simpler, shorter, no `<xsl:for-each>`, no XSLT conditional operators**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <size3><xsl:apply-templates/></size3>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parameter[@id=706]/value">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parameter[@id=706]/value[position() > 1]" priority="2">
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```